# converting excel file to pdf with phpexcel returning empty file

Tags: php, excel, pdf, yii2, phpexcel

I have an excel file and I want to convert the file to pdf using php excel. Using the following code:

```
namespace frontend\controllers;
use PHPExcel;
use PHPExcel_IOFactory;
use PHPExcel_Settings;
use PHPExcel_Style_Alignment;
use yii\web\Controller;

class ExportsController extends Controller
{
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $inputFile = \Yii::getAlias('@frontend') . '/controllers/matrix.xls';
        $inputFileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($inputFile);
        $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
        $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFile);
        $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

        $rendererLibrary = 'DomPDF';
        $rendererLibraryPath = \Yii::getAlias('@frontend') . '/components/Classes/PHPExcel/Writer/PDF/' . $rendererLibrary;
        $rendererLibraryPath .= '.php';

        if (!PHPExcel_Settings::setPdfRenderer(
            $rendererLibrary,
            $rendererLibraryPath
        )
        ) {
            die(
                'NOTICE: Please set the $rendererName and $rendererLibraryPath values' .
                '<br />' .
                'at the top of this script as appropriate for your directory structure'
            );
        }
        header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="01simple.pdf"');
        header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
        $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'PDF');
        $objWriter->save('php://output');
    }
}
```

When I comment the last two lines of code it is returning empty pdf file otherwise its throwing the following error: `net::ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE`.

Could you please help me to find the mistake of the code?

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in last

```
  header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
  header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="01simple.pdf"');
  header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
  $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'PDF');
  ob_end_clean();
  $objWriter->save('php://output');
```

Comment: When I put  $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'PDF'); before header it is not giving net::ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE but another error appered Unable to load PDF Rendering library

Comment: Load PDF Library using required_once

Answer (score 0):

if your xls file have more than around 3000 records, DomPDF will be generating memory error.

Comment: What do you suggest instead of DomPDF